# C# POST request with Json containing an array

Tags: c#, json, post

I have been using some simple requests in past to send JSON and they have been working fine. I basically take simple string, convert it to UTF-8 using
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
and send this using HttpWebRequest.

Now I have received a task to send a new POST request which will have an array of Ids and be of type

```
{
    "GroupID": "Named_ID",
    "ChildIds": [
        "76197272-24E4-4DD2-90B8-46FDDCC0D6CA",
        "D2B3A1AC-ACF6-EA11-A815-000D3A49E4F3",
        "ED53D968-00F4-EA11-A815-000D3A49E4F3"
    ]
}
```

The ChildIds are available in a List(String []) with me. I could loop through the records and create a similar long string and then convert to byteArray in UTF8 but I feel this can be done in a simpler way. Examples that I have seen on the forum of using array in JSON always appear to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject but I am not clear if I should use this and if I do then do I convert the serialised object to UTF8 like I did earlier and is it then ok to use in the HttpWebRequest.
Can someone please advice on the approach I should take.

Comment: You edited your question so that the `ChildIds` are no longer well-formed GUID strings.  I will delete my answer, since you changed your question.

Comment: I had a different thought but it would be similar to what I asked earlier ie in GUID format(though as a string not Guid type) so have reverted example back.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class structure to match your json,

```
public class Data
{
    public string GroupId {get;set;} 
    public List<string> ChildIds {get;set;} 
}
```

serialize the data with JsonConvert or any other.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Data>(str) ;
```

Post the serialized data with httpclient assuming you have it injected in your class already.

```
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var post = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
```

Comment: thanks but I am trying to send a request so would need to serialise if I did. Do I need to convert to UTF-8 and is it an issue with serialising before.

Comment: would like to use byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json); so that I can reuse existing code after that point. Would this method work on var json after  JsonConvert.SerializeObject ?

Comment: @bravopers If `GetBytes()` takes a serialized object as argument, it should work. If not, I have no idea

Comment: @bravopers Yes you could do that `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)` But I would advise you not to, this method is much better